# Is there any mention of this conflict and fight in original stories?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

I think all Batman movies are based on DC stories/comics (I don't know about comics thing much).

So is *Batman vs Superman: Dawn of Justice* also based on some story (story about Batman seeing Superman as threat to humanity and eventually making him against Superman) OR the director/producer just wanted some imaginary fight and conflict between these 2 favorite superheroes to lure audience?

I mean was it director/producer's own imagination?

Comment: While the question is framed differently, the answer will end up being a duplicate of this [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33458/8101).  Oh and if you aren't a comic book guy but want to see the Dark Night Returns story, I highly, highly recommend the two part animated movie.

Answer (score 1):

Most of it comes from the Dark Knight Returns. The events of the fight are a strong parallel to the battle between old man Batman and Supes. The motives and ends of the fights are completely different, however.